# local notification ios 7 swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have button with this action:

```
@IBAction func pressed() {
    var notif = UILocalNotification()
    notif.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
    notif.alertBody = "some text"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notif)
    notif.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
}
```

I press it, but nothings happen. What's the problem?

Comment: What do you expect to happen. As long a your app is running in the foreground the `UILocalNotification` is directly delivered to you app, no message is shown. When you app is in the background the toast message is shown.

Comment: @rckoenes o, i got it. But what if i want to recieve notifications even if app is running in the foreground?

Comment: You can't iOS delivers all (local and push) notification directly to you app if it is running in the foreground. And Apple has no API for access the notification center in the current SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
localNotification.alertBody = "Bienvenido a Neku!"
localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1       UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```